# Pandas remove particular int values in comma separated column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe  with column values separated by comma. I want to remove  certain values from those values.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
  col1             col2  
0,1,0,2,30,10,20  0,0,2,3,10,20
0,0,0,1,0,210,30  0,0,20,20,20,0,0,0
```

I want to remove 0,1,2 from column

Output should be:

```
 col1             col2                new_col1  new_col2
0,1,0,2,30,10,20  0,0,2,3,10,20       30,10,20   3,10,20
0,0,0,1,0,210,30  0,0,20,20,20,0,0,0   210,30    20,20,20
```

I tried

```
def mysub(r):

     lst = [float(a) for a in r.split(',') if a != '0' and a != '' and  a != "1" and  a != "2"]
     return lst
df['new_col1']=df[df['col1']].mysub()
```

I am not able fix my problem - help me to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with specified values for remove in list:

```
def mysub(r):
    return [','.join(z for z in str(y).split(',') 
            if z not in ['0','1','2']) for y in r]
df = df.apply(mysub)
print (df)
       col1      col2
0  30,10,20   3,10,20
1    210,30  20,20,20
```

For new columns:

```
def mysub(r):
    return [','.join(z for z in str(y).split(',') 
            if z not in ['0','1','2']) for y in r]
df = df.join(df.apply(mysub).add_prefix('new_'))
print (df)
               col1                col2  new_col1  new_col2
0  0,1,0,2,30,10,20       0,0,2,3,10,20  30,10,20   3,10,20
1  0,0,0,1,0,210,30  0,0,20,20,20,0,0,0    210,30  20,20,20
```

If want floats output:

```
def mysub(r):
    return [[float(z) for z in str(y).split(',') 
            if z not in ['0','1','2']] for y in r]
df = df.join(df.apply(mysub).add_prefix('new_'))
print (df)
               col1                col2            new_col1  \
0  0,1,0,2,30,10,20       0,0,2,3,10,20  [30.0, 10.0, 20.0]   
1  0,0,0,1,0,210,30  0,0,20,20,20,0,0,0       [210.0, 30.0]   

             new_col2  
0   [3.0, 10.0, 20.0]  
1  [20.0, 20.0, 20.0]
```

Comment: how can i apply mysub   to specific column in dataframe

Comment: @hemantcnaik - Change `df = df.apply(mysub)` to `df = df[['col1',''col2]].apply(mysub)`

Comment: i tried your code in some places  like 6,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6 and 7,0,0,0,1,7  its giving 616 and 717 respectively not comma sep values

Comment: still getting same problem one of column values are 0,11,16,45,0,38 its return 11164538

Comment: @hemantcnaik it seems some data related problem, is possible share real data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214049/discussion-between-hemant-c-naik-and-jezrael).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qSqZy564zWeOKw9vdZOVlGyRt4-hLLjC

Comment: in float condition working fine how can i remove the brackets

Comment: @hemantcnaik - Can you try to test change `y.split(',')` to `str(y).split(',')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: ','.join([e for e in x.split(',') if e not in ['0','1','2']]))
```